# Redux-thunk - How to structure fetched data to index storage pattern?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using Redux + Redux-thunk to fetch datas from my API.

The data returned by my thunk is an array that looks like this :

```
[
  {id_user: 1, name: "Joe", surname: "M", email: "joe@email.fr"},
  {id_user: 2, name: "Jimmy", surname: "S", email: "jimmy@email.fr"},
  {id_user: 9, name: "Jhonny", surname: "H", email: "jhonny@email.fr}
]
```

**What I would like to do but don't get how to, is to store this data in my global state using the index storage pattern.**

For exemple, from the fetched array showed above, the data structure I would like to store would look like this :

```
{
  "usersById": {
    1: {
      id_user: 1,
      name: "Joe", 
      surname: "M", 
      email: "joe@email.fr"
    },
    2: {
      id_user: 2, 
      name: "Jimmy", 
      surname: "S", 
      email: "jimmy@email.fr"
    },
    9: {
      id_user: 9,
      name: "Jhonny", 
      surname: "H", 
      email: "jhonny@email.fr
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I tried doing it in my success user fetch action creator :

```
export const fetchUsersSuccess = (users) => ({
    type: types.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    users: users.map(user => 
        'userById': {
            [user.id_user]: {
                id_user: user.id_user,
                name: user.name,
                surname: user.surname,
                email: user.email,
            }
        }
    }),
    loading: false,
});
```

The problem is, this still returns an array, looking like this :

```
[
  userById: {
    1: {
      id_user: 1
      name: "Joe"
      surname: "M"
    }
  },
  userById: {
    2: {
      id_user: 2
      name: "Jimmy"
      surname: "S"
    }
  },
  userById: {
    9: {
      id_user: 9,
      name: "Jhonny",
      surname: "H"
    }
  },
 
]
```

I searched around but could not get an answer for this. I also tried to format the fetched data from the fetching thunk directly but I think this is not the solution ? Am I wrong ?

Or maybe this logic should go to the reducer ?

I know this must be simple stuff but I can't get over it, making me trying over-complicated things for, I guess, something as simple as this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) specifically has a [`createEntityAdapter` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) that implements managing data in a normalized form in the store.

For examples of how to use it, see [the "Redux Essentials" core docs tutorial, Part 6: Performance and Normalizing Data](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization), and the ["Managing Normalized Data" section in the Redux Toolkit Usage Guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#managing-normalized-data).